# XSLT select elements in order they are

Tags: xslt

```
<root>
    <label></label>
    <title></title>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <list></list>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <label></label>
    <list></list>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</root>
```

Now I want to select the tags as they are in order

like first label, then title, then two p tags then list is that possible

Problem is when I am selecting tag `<p>` with "." it lists all the elements in the root

My XSLT is

```
<template match="root">
    <fo:block space-before="6pt" space-after="6pt" font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:value-of select="label" />
        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:for-each select="p">
            <fo:block space-before="6pt" space-after="6pt">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:for-each select="list/list-item">
            <fo:block>
                <fo:list-block provisional-distance-between-starts="3pc" provisional-label- separation="1pc">
                    <fo:list-item space-before="5pt" text-align="justify">
                        <fo:list-item-label>
                            <fo:block font-weight="bold" font-size="14pt">
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:list-item-label>
                        <fo:list-item-body>
                            <fo:block text-align="justify" font-size="10pt" font-weight="normal">
                                <xsl:value-of select="label" />
                                <xsl:value-of select="p" />
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:list-item-body>
                    </fo:list-item>
                </fo:list-block>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:block>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the XSLT you are currently using, and also what output you expect? Thank you.

Comment: @TimC - I have added my FO XSLT and this is what the structure I need. Thanks in advance

Comment: The XML that you have shared has one parent element `root` whereas all the other elements are child elements of `root`. In the XSL, you are not specifying which child element to access e.g. for-each `<p>` will select all the `p` elements under `root` and print the values for all the `p` elements. If you are looking to print the values of different child elements at different locations, you need to access the specific child element using its `position()` viz. `label[1]` or `title[1]` and so on.

Comment: Thank you @AniketV I will try to access them through position

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could benefit from a template approach. So have a template for each element you wish to process. For example, for converting `p` elements

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <fo:block space-before="6pt" space-after="6pt">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, in your template matching `root`, you just need to do this, to select the nodes in order

```
<xsl:apply-templates />
```

Having said that, it looks like you need to do extra work to wrap the first `title` and `label` in a block, so, your `root` template probably needs to look like this, which makes us of position to get the rest of the nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <fo:block space-before="6pt" space-after="6pt" font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:value-of select="label[1]" />
        <xsl:value-of select="title[1]" />
    </fo:block>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() > 2]" />
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT as a starting point

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="fo" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="root">
    <fo:block space-before="6pt" space-after="6pt" font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:value-of select="label[1]" />
        <xsl:value-of select="title[1]" />
    </fo:block>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() > 2]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <fo:block space-before="6pt" space-after="6pt">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list">
    <fo:list-block provisional-distance-between-starts="3pc" provisional-label-separation="1pc">
        <xsl:for-each select="list-item">
            <fo:list-item space-before="5pt" text-align="justify">
                <fo:list-item-label>
                    <fo:block font-weight="bold" font-size="14pt">
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-label>
                <fo:list-item-body>
                    <fo:block text-align="justify" font-size="10pt" font-weight="normal">
                        <xsl:value-of select="label" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="p" />
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:list-block>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In the template for `list`, remove the outer `fo:block` and put the `xsl:for-each` inside the `fo:list-block` so that you generate only one `fo:list-block` per list.  Doing this would be useful if, for example, there was different space before and after the list than between pairs of list items or if you wanted to keep the list on one page for some reason.